# if statement in .eq() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove li which index in less than five. So I am using .eq(). I Know it can be done using if statement but I want to use if statement in inside eq().

```
<ul>
<li>0</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>


$('li').each(function (i) {
    $(this).eq(function () {
        if (i < 5)
            return i;
        else
            return false;
    }).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) (less than) to get the elements with index less then give value.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4r3jU/)**

```
$('li:lt(5)').remove()
```

**Description:**  Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set, [reference](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).

> The index-related selectors (including this "less than" selector)
>   filter the set of elements that have matched the expressions that
>   precede them. They narrow the set down based on the order of the
>   elements within this matched set, [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**:lt() Selector**](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

```
$('li:lt(5)').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `:lt()` selector, you can also use [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('ul').children().slice(0, 4).remove();
```